# Plotting real-time Spectrogram from a input device

Tags: python, matplotlib, spectrogram, matplotlib-animation

I'm trying to plot in real-time a spectogram from the default input device data. I plot an animation using FuncAnimation from matplotlib module but I don't understand why the plot does not update with the new data from the buffer.

This is what I have so far.

```
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import rtmixer
import math
import sounddevice as sd

FRAMES_PER_BUFFER = 512
NFFT = 4096
NOVERLAP = 128

window = 100000
downsample = 10  
channels = 1

def create_specgram(frame):
    global plotdata
    
    spec, freqs, t = plt.mlab.specgram(plotdata[:,-1], Fs=samplerate)
    xmin, xmax = np.min(t) - pad_xextent, np.max(t) + pad_xextent
    extent = xmin, xmax, freqs[0], freqs[-1]
    arr = np.flipud(10. * np.log10(spec))

    return arr, extent

def update_plot(frame):

    global plotdata

    while ringBuffer.read_available >= FRAMES_PER_BUFFER:
        read, buf1, buf2 = ringBuffer.get_read_buffers(FRAMES_PER_BUFFER)
        assert read == FRAMES_PER_BUFFER
        buffer = np.frombuffer(buf1, dtype='float32')
        buffer.shape = -1, channels
        buffer = buffer[::downsample]

        assert buffer.base.base == buf1
        shift = len(buffer)
        plotdata = np.roll(plotdata, -shift, axis=0)
        plotdata[-shift:, :] = buffer
        ringBuffer.advance_read_index(FRAMES_PER_BUFFER)

    arr, _  = create_specgram(frame)
    image.set_array(arr)
    return image,

device_info = sd.query_devices(device=None, kind='input')
samplerate = device_info['default_samplerate']

pad_xextent = (NFFT - NOVERLAP) / samplerate / 2
length = int(window * samplerate / (1000 * downsample))
plotdata = np.zeros((length, channels))

stream = rtmixer.Recorder(device=None, channels=channels, blocksize=FRAMES_PER_BUFFER,
                          latency='low', samplerate=samplerate)

ringbufferSize = 2**int(math.log2(3 * samplerate))

ringBuffer = rtmixer.RingBuffer(channels * stream.samplesize, ringbufferSize)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 5))
arr, extent = create_specgram(0)
image = plt.imshow(arr, animated=True, extent=extent, aspect='auto')
fig.colorbar(image)

ani = FuncAnimation(fig, update_plot, interval=1, blit=True, cache_frame_data=False)           

with stream:
    ringBuffer = rtmixer.RingBuffer(channels * stream.samplesize, ringbufferSize)
    action = stream.record_ringbuffer(ringBuffer)
    plt.show()
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

I would expect something like this moving from right to left.

[image]

And this is what I get (I'm playing something different than just noise):

[image: Result from previous code]

Comment: good question, but too much code, please reduce to this:
[minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: My bad, I updated the code with minimal lines.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works perfectly for me, updating as you described!

Therefore, the answer is lying in your system.

I started it under a linux computer from the console, it did not work inside an IDE (spyder), because there, the ouput settings don't allow to start a separate window.

Small side note: you have to set limits to the color scale, otherwise it keeps it fixed from the starting value, which is 1 in your case.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Did you try while playing somethind on the input device, does the spectrogram updates as desired? 
How exactly the system can be causing this issue?

Comment: Yes, this is what I mean: It reacts to the microphone and updates the plot. Meanwhile also checked on Windows, running Anaconda, here it works, too.
With "system" I mean mostly how you use Python. As mentioned: try it outside an IDE, just from the command line, since IDEs often redirect plots a little bit.